# Calling constructors via reflection without casting using generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a bunch of classes that all have the same constructor signature. I have a method that returns an object of that type based on some arguments (which are not the same arguments in the constructor), but I can't seem to figure out how to make a generic method that works for all classes.

Separated as different methods, I may have something like this:

```
public ImplementationClassA getClassA(long id)
{
    SomeGenericThing thing = getGenericThing(id);
    return new ImplementationClassA(thing);
}

public ImplementationClassB getClassB(long id)
{
    SomeGenericThing thing = getGenericThing(id);
    return new ImplementationClassB(thing);
}
```

As you can see, they're strikingly similar, just the implementation class is different. How do I make a generic method to handle all implementation classes, assuming they have the same constructor?

I took a stab at it, but it's not working because `T` isn't recognized... but it feels like something similar to what I want:

```
public T getImplementationClass(Class<T> implementationClass, long id)
{
    SomeGenericThing thing = getGenericThing(id);
    return implementationClass.getConstructor(SomeGenericThing.class)
                              .newInstance(thing);
}
```

The caller could now simply do `getImplementationClass(ImplementationClassA.class, someID)`.

Is this even possible with reflection and generic types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generics syntax needs `T` to be declared.  In a generic method, place the declaration of the generic type parameter in `<>` (e.g. `<T>`) before the return type, which is `T`:

```
public <T> T getImplementationClass(Class<T> implementationClass, long id)
```

If all your implementation classes implement some interface or subclass some base class, then you may want to place a bound on `T`:

```
public <T extends BaseClassOrInterface> T getImplementationClass(
    Class<T> implementationClass, long id)
```

Comment: They do indeed extend an abstract class. I knew I was missing something with the generics! Usually when I use them, they're defined at the class level (e.g. `implements SomeInterface<ImplClass1,ImplClass2>`), but I've not done a method like this before. Thanks!